# QEMU kernel for raspberry pi 3 with networking and virtio support

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, raspberry-pi3, virtualization, qemu

I used the QEMU(qemu-system-aarch64 -M raspi3) for emulating the Raspberry pi3 with the kernel from the working image. Everything was working but there was no networking.

```
qemu-system-aarch64 \
   -kernel ./bootpart/kernel8.img \
   -initrd ./bootpart/initrd.img-4.14.0-3-arm64 \
   -dtb ./debian_bootpart/bcm2837-rpi-3-b.dtb \
   -M raspi3 -m 1024 \
   -nographic \
   -serial mon:stdio \
   -append "rw earlycon=pl011,0x3f201000 console=ttyAMA0 loglevel=8 root=/dev/mmcblk0p3 fsck.repair=yes net.ifnames=0 rootwait memtest=1" \
   -drive file=./genpi64lite.img,format=raw,if=sd,id=hd-root \
   -no-reboot
```

I tried to add this option

```
-device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd-root \
-netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22 \
-device virtio-net-device,netdev=net0 \
```

But there would be an error

qemu-system-aarch64: -device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd-root: No 'virtio-bus' bus found for device 'virtio-blk-device'
I have referenced some forum, and used the "virt" machine instead of raspi3 in order of emulating virtio-network

```
qemu-system-aarch64 \
  -kernel ./bootpart/kernel8.img \
  -initrd ./bootpart/initrd.img-4.14.0-3-arm64 \
  -m 2048 \
  -M virt \
  -cpu cortex-a53 \
  -smp 8 \
  -nographic \
  -serial mon:stdio \
  -append "rw root=/dev/vda3 console=ttyAMA0 loglevel=8 rootwait fsck.repair=yes memtest=1" \
  -drive file=./genpi64lite.img,format=raw,if=sd,id=hd-root \
  -device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd-root \
  -netdev user,id=net0,net=192.168.1.1/24,dhcpstart=192.168.1.234 \
       -device virtio-net-device,netdev=net0 \
  -no-reboot
```

There is nothing printed and the terminal was suspended. It means the kernel does not work with virt machine.

I decided to build for my own custom kernel. Could anyone give me advice for options to build the kernel that works with both the QEMU and the virtio?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14):

The latest versions of QEMU (5.1.0 and 5.0.1) have USB emulation for the raspi3 machine (qemu-system-aarch64 -M raspi3).

You can emulate networking and access to SSH if you use: -device usb-net,netdev=net0 -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22 in QEMU

I tested this configuration, and I got this:

The USB network device in QEMU raspi3
[image: USB network device in QEMU raspi3]

Ethernet interface in QEMU raspi3
[image: Ethernet interface in QEMU raspi3]

Here the full command and options that I used:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -m 1024 -M raspi3 -kernel kernel8.img -dtb bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb -sd 2020-08-20-raspios-buster-armhf.img -append "console=ttyAMA0 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootwait rootfstype=ext4" -nographic -device usb-net,netdev=net0 -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22
```

The QEMU version used was 5.1.0.

Comment: In my setup, I can see `Netchip Technology` in `lsusb` but I do not see `eth0` in `ifconfig`. Could you please provide more details how you got to the point where `eth0` shows up?

Comment: @peter.babic I edited the answer with the command and options that I used.

Comment: @lmcapacho, I already tried `qemu-system-aarch64 -m 1024 -M raspi3 -kernel kernel8.img -dtb bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb -sd 2020-08-20-raspios-buster-armhf.img -append "console=ttyAMA0 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootwait rootfstype=ext4" -nographic -device usb-net,netdev=net0 -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22
`

But I can not see `eth0` in `ifconfig` also, my qemu version is 5.2.50
[https://imgur.com/3ws7646](https://imgur.com/3ws7646)

Comment: @xuanloctn I tried again using QEMU version 5.2.0 and the kernel and the device tree from the _2021-01-11-raspios-buster-armhf_ image, and it worked. I recommend you check if the ** cdc_ether ** and ** cdc_subset ** drivers exist with the `lsmod` command. Also, check the boot status of the USB network with the `dmesg | grep "usb\|cdc"` command.

Comment: Wow, I spent hours trying to boot bullseye on Ubuntu focal and thought it was hopeless. But this worked first time. Thank you. Specifically, I compiled QEMU 6.2.0 from source, then ran: `qemu-img resize -f raw 2022-01-28-raspios-bullseye-arm64.img 4G` and then `qemu-6.2.0/build/qemu-system-aarch64 -m 1024 -M raspi3b -kernel kernel8.img -dtb bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb -drive file=2022-01-28-raspios-bullseye-arm64.img,if=sd,format=raw -append "console=ttyAMA0 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootwait rootfstype=ext4" -nographic -device usb-net,netdev=net0 -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22`.

Comment: @xuanloctn @peter.babic Did you resolve your issue eventually? I also do not see `eth0` in `ifconfig`

Answer (score 7):

I have had the same problems as user @peterbabic, in that while I could see the gadget with `lsusb`, I could not see any net device.

So I tried manually inserting the appropriate module `g_ether` -- and it said that *it could not find the driver*.

It was then that I realized that the `kernelv8.img` file I had downloaded and the Raspbian OS image that I was booting **were different versions**, so the kernel could not find its modules because it looked for them in the wrong directory.

On the other hand, the Raspbian OS image **had** the correct kernel in its first partition (I could see it in /boot). The only problem was getting it out and use it to replace the wrong `kernelv8.img` (I could not find the correct one online -- and anyway, the kernel of the Raspbian image is by definition *more correct*).

So, I copied the Raspbian OS image on my Linux box, and mounted it with loop:

```
# fdisk raspbian.img
  - command "p" lists partitions and tells me that P#1 starts at sector 2048
  - command "q" exits without changes
# losetup -o $[ 2048 * 512 ] /dev/loop9 raspbian.img # because sectors are 512 bytes
# mkdir /mnt/raspi
# mount /dev/loop9 /mnt/raspi
  - now "ls -la /mnt/raspi" shows the content of image partition 1, with kernels
# cp /mnt/raspi/kernel8.img .
# umount /mnt/raspi
# losetup -d /dev/loop9 # destroy loop device
# rmdir /mnt/raspi # remove temporary mount point
# rm raspbian.img
  - I no longer need the raspbian.img copy so I delete it.
  - now current directory holds "kernel8.img". I can just copy it back.
```

To be sure, I also modified /boot/cmdline.txt on the Raspberry image (before rebooting with the new kernel) so that it now added the dwc and g_ether modules:

[image]

On boot, the gadget is now automatically recognized:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I had exactly this problem which had been caused by me running apt update inside the Pi VM, which updated its kernel.. every time this happens, copying the kernel8.img outside must happen.

Comment: you are my hero, thx it was an older kernel8.img

Answer (score 3):

Your raspi3 command line has no networking because on a raspi3 the networking is via USB, and QEMU doesn't have a model of the USB controller for that board yet. Adding virtio-related options won't work, because the raspi3 has no PCI and so there's no way to plug in a pci virtio device.

Your command line option with virt looks basically right (at least enough so to boot; you probably want "if=none" rather than "if=sd" and I'm not sure if the network options are quite right, but if those parts are wrong they will result in errors from the guest kernel later rather than total lack of output). So your problem is likely that the kernel config is missing some important items.

You can boot a stock Debian kernel on the virt board (instructions here: https://translatedcode.wordpress.com/2017/07/24/installing-debian-on-qemus-64-bit-arm-virt-board/) so one approach you could take to finding the error in your kernel config is to compare your config with the one the Debian kernel has. The upstream kernel source 'defconfig' also should work. I find that starting with a configm that works and cutting it down is faster than building one up from nothing by trying to find all the obscure options that need to be present.

Comment: I understand that raspi3 model does not support pci virtio option.
It means there is no way to work with networking for raspi3 on QEMU, doesn't it?

Comment: I tried the kernel vmlinuz-4.14.0-3-arm64 and initrd.img-4.14.0-3-arm64 from debian distribution with qemu-system-aarch64, virt machine.
It works great but I do not know the .config file for building the kernel.
Because I want to add some module, I must build a custom one for my own.

Answer (score 2):

I've updated the steps needed to get this working with April 4th [Raspios](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/operating-systems/#raspberry-pi-os-64-bit)

```
# wget https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_arm64/images/raspios_lite_arm64-2022-04-07/2022-04-04-raspios-bullseye-arm64-lite.img.xz
# unxz 2022-04-04-raspios-bullseye-arm64-lite.img.xz
# mkdir boot
# mount -o loop,offset=4194304 2022-04-04-raspios-bullseye-arm64-lite.img boot
# cp boot/bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb kernel8.img .
# echo 'pi:$6$6jHfJHU59JxxUfOS$k9natRNnu0AaeS/S9/IeVgSkwkYAjwJfGuYfnwsUoBxlNocOn.5yIdLRdSeHRiw8EWbbfwNSgx9/vUhu0NqF50' > boot/userconf
# umount boot
# qemu-img convert -f raw -O qcow2 2022-04-04-raspios-bullseye-arm64-lite.img  2022-04-04-raspios-bullseye-arm64-lite.qcow2
# qemu-img resize 2022-04-04-raspios-bullseye-arm64-lite.qcow2 4g
```

Then run Qemu 7.1.0 this way:

```
# qemu-system-aarch64 -m 1024 -M raspi3b -kernel kernel8.img \
  -dtb bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb -sd 2022-04-04-raspios-bullseye-arm64-lite.qcow2 \
  -append "console=ttyAMA0 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootwait rootfstype=ext4" \
  -nographic -device usb-net,netdev=net0 -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22
```

Edit your /boot/cmdline.txt file to add `modules-load=dwc2,g_ether` to /boot/cmdline.txt after rootwait.